# Choosing between Negative Binomial, Zero-Truncated NB, and NB with Arithmetically Altered Outcome (SAS)

Tags: regression, distributions, modeling, negative-binomial-distribution, sas

I am modeling longitudinal Days of Pill Supply with predictors Number of Rx's and Patient Race. I was not able to use linear regression (proc reg or proc glm) because of heteroscedastic residuals, so I tried negative binomial regression. Days of Pill Supply is over dispersed (conditional variances much larger than means, dispersion parameter confidence interval in negbin model does not overlap zero). When I run a negative binomial model I have statistically significant results in line with my hypothesis. I have used these two commands to arrive at results with similar parameters and with identical p values fully in line with my hypothesis:

```
*Model 1;
proc genmod data=data;
class  race;
model PillSupply= RxTotal race  / type3 dist=negbin ; 
run;  

*Model 2;
proc fmm data=data cov;
class  race;
model PillSupply= RxTotal race / dist=NEGBIN; 
ods output parameterestimates=pe cov=covb;
run;
```

However, I read that because PillSupply is zero-truncated (everyone in the dataset had at least 30 days), I should use zero-truncated negative binomial regression. Therefore, I ran this:

```
*Model 3;
proc fmm data=data cov;
class  race;
model PillSupply = RxTotal race / dist=TRUNCNEGBIN; 
ods output parameterestimates=pe cov=covb;
run;
```

From this, the parameter estimates are in the same ballpark as Models 1&2, but the p values are all way larger (>.1). Just to experiment, I decided to arithmetically alter the outcome so it was no longer zero-truncated by substracting 30 (30 days is the smallest total pill supply). When I did this, and ran this command:

```
*Model 4;
proc fmm data=data cov;
class  race;
model PillSupplyBeyond30Days = RxTotal race / dist=NEGBIN; 
ods output parameterestimates=pe cov=covb;
run;
```

My parameter estimates again stayed similar to the prior Models and the p values moved towards my hypothesized values (and the p value for the categorical variable value that I have seen the most consistent strong effect for across data exploration moved to <.05).
Can anyone provide some guidance to help me figure out which of these are correct / reasonable to present, or what further steps I need to take in order to decide? Thank you!

Comment: IMO - it doesn't make sense to run a NB regresssion if the values are all > 30. Neither does it make sense to run zero-truncated, if it's actually truncated at 30. The last option which you proposed, sounds like the best option. Or if SAS has an option, run a generally-truncated NB where the truncation parameter is 30 rather than 0. (I am guess you use SAS? I am not familiar with it)

Comment: I don't think the p-value should be the primary assessor of whether your model is right though...